# Java - Remove thread from memory

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a java desktop application that open a new JFrame (inside a thread) from another JFrame. Is there a way to remove a thread from the memory?

Comment: Are you trying just to close the second `JFrame`?

Comment: yes i want to close the second JFrame

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A thread is not a Java object. It is a native resource (thread of execution). The thread will be "removed from memory" as soon as it has finished running its code.

From Java's perspective, the thread is dead as soon as its `run()` method completes.

As for the `Thread` instance in charge of a particular thread of execution, it behaves just like any other Java object and is reclaimable by the Garbage Collector as soon as no references to it exist (and the underlying thread is not alive).

Comment: but thats not happening in my case...my application spawns 400 threads a t a time and when the run functions is completed...then main thread again pull data and spawn 400 child threads...
but the application gives OOM(Unable to create Native Thread) after 18-20 hours of running...

Comment: You probably have a thread leak, some threads get stuck forever.

Comment: for this..i checked the status of every thread after run function is completed....but they all seems to be not Alive....
What could be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to actually remove a Thread object from memory. Like with any other object, if there are no references to it, it will be garbage-collected the next time a gc runs.